# Short fantasy story where the plot twist is the main characters are cats

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a short fantasy story in an anthology where the two main characters are waiting nervously for their God to return to them, the main thrust of the story is their relationship with each other and with their God. The plot twist comes in the final paragraph, when we find out the main characters are in fact house cats. 
Any ideas anyone? Thanks.

Comment: Arrgh!  I feel like I just read something about a pet thinking its master was a god recently.  But I don't remember where nor even if it was fiction.

Comment: Nothing from TVTROPES WARNING https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/TomatoSurprise/Literature seems to match.  The closest is "Just Good Friends" by Jeffry Archer.